# How to check if the user is a guest or logged in at laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth, laravel-passport

`Auth()->check()` keeps returning false. The api is has api middleware only and I want both guests and logged in users to use it.

I tried taking the authorization token from the request header, but I don't know of any way to check which user has this token.

```php
if(Auth()->check()){
        //return extra data
} else {
        //return something else
}
```

Why is `Auth()->check()` is always returning false even though Ive bearer token inside the header?? It should return true if the header has a token

Comment: The default guard is web, so this might ```work auth('api')->check()```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> you may specify guard name

```
if(auth('api')->check()){
          //return extra data
} else {
         //return something else
}
```